# Send a json payload to Apache Kafka topic in Spring

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I need to send (Post) Json payload to Apache Kafka topic but I am receiving the following error :-
 ***"message": "Can't convert value of class com.xyz.User to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer"***

Also Spring shows class cast exception :-
    ***java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xyz.User cannot be cast to java.lang.String***

Following is my modal,kafka config and controller

```
public class User {
    private String firstname;
    private String email;


    public User() {}
    public User(String firstname, String email) {
        super();
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserModel [firstname=" + firstname + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }


}
```

**Kafka Configuration**

```
 package config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;

import com.xyz.User;

@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, User> producerFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);

    }
     @Bean
        public KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate() {
            return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
        }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/kafka")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;

    private static String TOPIC = "kafka-producer";
    @PostMapping("/publish")
    public void getUserId(@RequestBody User user) {

        kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, user);
```

**Json Payload send from postman**

```
{
    "firstname" : "xyz",
    "email" : "xyz@gmail.com.com"

}
```

Comment: the producer is configured in xml? can you post that one as well?

Comment: @aurelius , I am using spring-boot , i don't have any xml configurations for producer.

Comment: then you need the KafkaTemplate, which is used to send the messages

Comment: yes i am trying to send via kafkatemplate  kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, user);

Comment: can you post that code as well, I think you did not change the type of the message that you send, from string to User

Comment: can you post the import statements of config class

Comment: added import statements as suggested by Deadpool

Comment: wondering if you have a content-type set to json type in your request headers?

Comment: If you are want to send only USER than you can create your own converter and specify it in the kafka configuration. if you use String serializer/deserializer or json well, you have to pass a string or json, depends on your requirements.

Comment: @Nishu Tayal - content type is set to Json(application/json) in postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to reproduce your error at my local setup.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class com.example.demo.User to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.demo.User cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

If we look at log then it says `value.serializer` value still referring to default `StringSerializer` rather than expected is `JsonSerializer` which in turn says your producer configuration are not getting into effect. In short your `KafkaCOnfiguration` class is not being referred.

Your `KafkaConfiguration` class is in some `config` package and `User` class in some com.xyz package. So solution would be to make sure that it gets picks up your configuration. Most probably that package may not getting scanned for configuration/beans definition. If you move KafkaConfiguration to root package of your application then your original code should work fine.

If you say that your KafkaTemplate object getting injected then it's actually not. The one which is getting injected is defined by Spring kafka Autoconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Service

```
@Service
public class KafkaSenderService {

  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<String, JsonNode> kafkaTemplate;

  public void send(String kafkaTopic, JsonNode message) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaTopic, message);
  }
}
```

Controller

```
for (JsonNode data: datas) {
   kafkaSender.send(topicName,data);
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Answer (score -1):

Following worked for me.

```
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

private static String TOPIC = "kafka-producer";
@PostMapping("/publish")
public void getUserId(@RequestBody User user) {
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String json = null;
    try {
        json = ow.writeValueAsString(user);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, json);


}
```

Comment: For performance reasons, move the ObjectWriter declaration outside of the method, and don't pretty print the message

Comment: However, Spring should already know how to use Jackson to convert your objects https://codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-json-serializer-deserializer-example.html

Comment: Yes. you don't need to manually serialze. JsonSerializer internally usage ObjectMapper so it will work with User object as well. Refer my answer to correct your config and more details