# Send Raw Json to Kafka Topic in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm tring to send json-string to Kafka topic, using Java.
There are many similar threads out there such as:

- [Send a json payload to Apache Kafka topic in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388646/send-a-json-payload-to-apache-kafka-topic-in-spring)
- [Sending Json Object to kafka topic in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513153/sending-json-object-to-kafka-topic-in-java)

My Code Snippet

```
String body = "{\"theKey\":\"theValue\"}";

var record = new ProducerRecord<>(String, null, new ObjectMapper().readTree(body));

...

properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class.getName());
properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class.getName());
var producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);

...

producer.send(record, callback);
```

Alternatively,

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
public class POJO {
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id= id;
    }

    String id;
}

...

var pojoBytes = new ObjectMapper().objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(POJO);

var record = new ProducerRecord<>(String, null, pojoBytes); // Given that ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG is now ByteArraySerializer
```

Context

- I've tried JsonSerializer
- I've tried Custom Serializer that pretty much mimics what OOB JsonSerializer does
- I'm able to publish successfully to Kafka topic without any issue.

But what I'm seeing in the Kafka topic is the following (through lenses):

```
VALUE:"{"theKey":"theValue"}"
```

Expectation is:

```
VALUE:{"theKey":"theValue"}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest not using lenses or any UI tool that would hide deserializer logic. Write a consumer in Java and compare what deserializer works. Otherwise, just use kafka-console-producer rather than write code since that's still "using Java"

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for your response! I know my question was bit tough, especially to those who never used tool like lenses before. With your hint, I was able to figure out lenses configuration. I'll answer my own question below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out Lenses had configuration setting where value can either be displayed as `String` or `JSON`, as shown below.

[image]

With this change, the value now displays as Json as I wanted it to be.